# How to implement AT command call in my application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, at-command, aidl

I have to fetch some low level information like RxLev, BLER, RxQual etc which are not accessible through Android framework APIs. I found the alternative to be AT command. I am using rooted Samsung galaxy S. On previous post, there are many confusion regarding the process to send AT command. In some post it is answered but when I tried adb shell -> su -> echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0. It doesnt show the result.Could you please provide information on:

1. Is it possible to fetch the required info using AT command?
2. Is it possible to call the AT command through adb shell & in 3rd party Android app?
3. Should I need to do AIDL/NDK implementation and talk to RIL/kernel?
4. Process to do ?

Please let me know if I am in wrong direction.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

-Shravan

Comment: check this out http://tech-papers.org/executing-at-commands-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

If you have busybox installed you could use `microcom` applet:

```
echo "AT\r" | busybox microcom -t 500 /dev/smd0
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I installed & launched Busybox 1.20.2 on rooted HTC Hero device. Connected it with pc through USB. In command prompt run foll commands; 1). adb shell -> su -> echo "AT\r" | busybox microcom -t 500 /dev/smd0  2). echo "AT+CLAC" | busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/ttyGS0. But both gives segmentation fault. Any idea & is it the right way to send the AT command ??

Comment: Getting segmentation fault is rather unexpected. I suspect there's something wrong with your busybox binary. Other than that you need to make sure that you are using proper tty device. Sometimes the device is not created by default. Check if any of the init scripts mention a service which takes any "/dev/tty*" or "/dev/smd*" as a parameter.

Comment: Hey Alex,,, Is it possible to use `busybox microcom` from another app ? Let's say I create an app in Android Studio and I'd like to launch `microcom` from there and read the results in an app variable...Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program to very easily send AT commands and retrieve the response:

```
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/smd0 -
AT
OK
$
```

Comment: Hey... Is it possible to do that from inside and Android App programmed with android studio ?

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer over there after writing my comment here....Now since I'm not a very advanced developer, I'm trying to figure out how to perform the steps you wrote there...So right now I'm stuck at step 0.  ;-)  Hopefully I'll find something